# Why does my mouse cursor starts to move slowly after I plug in USB webcam?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, usb, webcam

For some unknown reason my mouse cursor starts to move slowly after I plug in USB webcam(I have tried using two different ones). Cursor moves at least two or three times slower.

Why dos this happen? How to fix this?

This only disappears after I plug out webcam and restart PC.

Mouse is Microsoft USB IntelliMouse Optical.

I'm using Windows XP SP3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If memory serves, the operating system polls the USB bus, meaning that if your web cam or USB bus is poorly implemented (in its driver), it may be leaving the USB bus in a odd state.
I would check for a USB bus driver update.

Also, your OS would be useful information.

Comment: This is exactly what happens. Theoretically, a single USB device can hog the whole bandwidth and possible lock out the other devices. Then the OS is forced to kill the driver.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem but on windows 7, my solution is to unplug the mouse and plug it again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a different combination of USB ports? If you have some front facing ports, trying putting one device in there and the other in the rear. Also check you have the latest motherboard drivers.

Comment: No front facing ports. I have ~ 6 ports at the back. Tried plugging it in all of them. Have plugged in all sorts of USB devices before and nothing had made my USB mouse cursor to move slowly.